# iOS: What's the best way to detect a file's encoding

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, gb2312, big5

In some cases, I really need to know a file's encoding while reading the file. Sometimes we can do as [Apple's String Programming Guide suggest :](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459-SW1)

> **Reading data with an unknown encoding**
>
> If you find yourself with text of unknown encoding, it is best to make
>   sure that there is a mechanism for correcting the inevitable errors.
>   For example, Apple's Mail and Safari applications have encoding menus,
>   and TextEdit allows the user to reopen the file with an explicitly
>   specified encoding.
>
> If you are forced to guess the encoding (and note that in the absence
>   of explicit information, it is a guess):
>
> 1. Try stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: or initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: (or the URL-based
>      equivalents).
>
>    These methods try to determine the encoding of the resource, and if
>      successful return by reference the encoding used.
> 2. If (1) fails, try to read the resource by specifying UTF-8 as the encoding.
> 3. If (2) fails, try an appropriate legacy encoding.
>
>    "Appropriate" here depends a bit on circumstances; it might be the
>      default C string encoding, it might be ISO or Windows Latin 1, or
>      something else, depending on where your data are coming from.
> 4. Finally, you can try NSAttributedString's loading methods from the Application Kit (such as
>      initWithURL:options:documentAttributes:error:).
>
>    These methods attempt to load plain text files, and return the
>      encoding used. They can be used on more-or-less arbitrary text
>      documents, and are worth considering if your application has no
>      special expertise in text. They might not be as appropriate for
>      Foundation-level tools or documents that are not natural-language
>      text.

Here I came into some problem. Sometimes I can know the error. For example when I read a GB2312 encoding file using UTF8 way, then I will get nil, so I know the error. But when I read GB2312 encoding file using BIG5 way, I can't know the error.

NSAttributedString's init method may work on Mac, but when it comes to iOS, it needs iOS7, not so good.

I also search for it and find some discussing about it like [this on cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/302318-how-to-detect-string-encoding-before-reading-file-in-nsstring.html), but also on Mac. Then how about on iOS?

Comment: I'm handing a big file and have to read it chunk by chunk